# Java date with timezone changed secretly?

Tags: java, date, timezone

we have a webservices application that always takes the input of time in its UTC format as

2012-12-06T05:00:00.000Z

and here is the code that parse the date into a java util Date object

```
 private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
"(\\d{4})(?:-(\\d{2}))?(?:-(\\d{2}))?(?:[Tt](?:(\\d{2}))?(?::(\\d{2}))?(?::(\\d{2}))?(?:\\.(\\d{3}))?)?([Zz])?(?:([+-])(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}))?");


  Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(dateString);
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  int hoff = 0, moff = 0, doff = -1;
  if (m.group(9) != null) {
    doff = m.group(9).equals("-") ? 1 : -1;
    hoff = doff * (m.group(10) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(10)) : 0);
    moff = doff * (m.group(11) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(11)) : 0);
  }
  c.set(Calendar.YEAR,        Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
  c.set(Calendar.MONTH,       m.group(2) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(2))-1 : 0);
  c.set(Calendar.DATE,        m.group(3) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)) : 1);
  c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, m.group(4) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(4)) + hoff: 0);
  c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,      m.group(5) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(5)) + moff: 0);
  c.set(Calendar.SECOND,      m.group(6) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(6)) : 0);
  c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, m.group(7) != null ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(7)) : 0);
  return c.getTime();
```

Recently an odd thing was observed that as the application first starts, the returned date will be just correctly printed as 
Thur Dec 06 00:00:00 EST 2012

since we are in EST timezone. Then after a while, after some execution, even without restart the application, the same date would be printed as
Thur Dec 06 05:00:00 UTC 2012

I have been digging down in the application and I don't see any changes that would reset the default timezone of our application. How could that happen? It has been a week since we started working on this and we are still clueless :-(

Also, is there anyway to make sure the application keeps using the system timezone as that would not be changing?

thanks a lot for any help/hints

Comment: why did you not use javax.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(String) ???

Comment: also posted https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2452390&tstart=0

Comment: it is some 3rd party code we've been using since the first day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the TimeZone can be changed out from under your application by any poorly written code which decides to call `TimeZone.setDefault`.  we were actually bitten by this in our application when third-party code called that method.  the solution, unfortunately, is to *never* depend on the default TimeZone past the beginning of the application.  we have a core class which gets the default TimeZone on startup, and all subsequent code which needs to output dates using the system default *will explicitly use this stashed instance* (which is of course protected against modification, don't forget that TimeZone is mutable!).